# If Else Troubleshoot

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

The function is fairly self explanatory, but for some reason I cannot get this to work:

```
var windowWidth;

$(document).ready( function(){
    windowWidth = $(window).width();
    console.log(windowWidth);
});

$(window).resize( function(){
    windowWidth = $(window).width();
    console.log(windowWidth);
});


if (windowWidth > 600) {
    $('input').click( function(){

        var $inputname = $(this).attr('name');
        $('label[for="' + $inputname + '"]').removeClass('repositioned');

    });
}

else {
    $('input').click( function(){

        var $inputname = $(this).attr('name');
        $('label[for="' + $inputname + '"]').addClass('clear');

    });
}
```

If the window is larger than 600, the click should run the if statement; and if it is less, than it should run the else statement, but it is not running the second portion? I have looked thoroughly through it, and cannot figure out why it isn't acting appropriately.

Comment: If you want this to work *on click*, the entire if/else has to be **inside** the event handler.

Comment: the else will only work if the `input` is clicked. instead of checking the width and then adding the click event inside you can just have the click event and check the width inside it.  try this `$('input').click(function() {

     if (windowWidth > 600) {
         var $inputname = $(this).attr('name');
         $('label[for="' + $inputname + '"]').removeClass('repositioned');

     } else {
         var $inputname = $(this).attr('name');
         $('label[for="' + $inputname + '"]').addClass('clear');
     }

 });`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be doing the if/else branching inside of the event handler function:

```
var windowWidth;

$(document).ready( function(){
  windowWidth = $(window).width();
  console.log(windowWidth);
});

$(window).resize( function(){
  windowWidth = $(window).width();
  console.log(windowWidth);
});

$('input').click( function(){
  var $inputname;

  if (windowWidth > 600) {
    $inputname = $(this).attr('name');
    $('label[for="' + $inputname + '"]').removeClass('repositioned');
  } else {
    $inputname = $(this).attr('name');
    $('label[for="' + $inputname + '"]').addClass('clear');
  }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your javascript function to this

```
$('input').click(function () {
    if (windowWidth > 600) {

        var $inputname = $(this).attr('name');
        $('label[for="' + $inputname + '"]').removeClass('repositioned');
        console.log("> 600");
    } else {

        var $inputname = $(this).attr('name');
        $('label[for="' + $inputname + '"]').addClass('clear');
        console.log("< 600");
    };
});
```